# bibentry does not work when bbl filename differs from tex filename

Tags: bibliographies, bibentry, bbl

I have an issue with the latex package bibentry. I manually create a bbl file that I use as input at the end of my document to generate the list of references. Furthermore, I also print some references before the final list of references using the command `\bibitem`. This works fine as long as the bbl file has the same filename as the tex file. However, I would like to use a different filename for the bbl file. I appreciate any comments on how to achieve this.

Let us assume that the tex file has the name `my_doc.tex`. The following tex file is a minimal working example.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{filecontents}{my_doc.bbl}
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}

  \bibitem{latexcompanion}
  Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
  \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}.
  Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

  \end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

You may have a look at the companion by Goossens et al.~\cite{latexcompanion}

\nobibliography{my_doc}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\cite{latexcompanion}]
  \bibentry{latexcompanion}.
\end{itemize}

\input{my_doc.bbl}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following (desired) output.
[image: Good Result]

Next, I rename the bbl file (while keeping the name for the tex file):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{filecontents}{my_refs.bbl}
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}

  \bibitem{latexcompanion}
  Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
  \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion}.
  Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, 1993.

  \end{thebibliography}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

You may have a look at the companion by Goossens et al.~\cite{latexcompanion}

\nobibliography{my_refs}
\begin{itemize}
  \item[\cite{latexcompanion}]
  \bibentry{latexcompanion}.
\end{itemize}

\input{my_refs.bbl}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result. Note that now the `\bibitem` command does not create any output. I find this issue to be not documented in the [bibentry documentation](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf).
[image: Bad Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bibentry` package defines the `\nobibliography` command, which internally calls `\bibliography`. The definition of `\bibliography` is as follows:

```
\if@filesw
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{\zap@space#1\@empty }}
\fi
\@input@{\jobname.bbl}
```

This shows that LaTeX tries to load `\jobname.bbl`. The `\jobname` macro is used for the current filename. This does not work if you use a different filename for the `.bbl` file, and LaTeX shows a warning about this in the log file.

As a quick solution you can temporarily redefine `\jobname` when calling `\nobibliography`:

```
\let\origjobname\jobname
\def\jobname{my_refs}
\nobibliography{my_refs}
\let\jobname\origjobname
```